# Array iteration only showing first letter on react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, iteration

On optn we have following data

```
"optn": [
    "ഫത്തേപ്പൂര്  സിക്രി",
    "ഖജൂരാഹോ ക്ഷേത്രം",
    "ചാര്മിനാര്",
    "കുത്തബ്മീനാര്"
],
```

iteration done as below,but while calling example[0] getting only first letter like 
        "ഫ",
        "ഖ",
        "ച",
        "ക"
on 'example' only getting error

> Invariant Violation:Objects are not valid as a react child(found:
>   object with  keys{key,index}) if you meant to render a collection of children use an array instead

```
objAns= this.state.optn.map((example,index) =>{
  return(
    <View  key={index.toString()} >
    <RadioButton currentValue={this.state.value} value={index+1} onPress={this.handleOnPress.bind(this)}>
    <Text>{example[0]}</Text>
    </RadioButton>
  </View>
  );
});
```

if we using {example[0]}{example[1]}{example[2]}then we get next letters and if optn contain English words then no problem it will work but i have to manage these type of data so how to solve such issue. is it possible to use 'for loop' inside ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's weird but this seems to work :

```
<Text>{example.toString()}</Text>
```

Comment: Invariant Violation:Objects are not valid as a react child(found: object with  keys{key,index})

Comment: that's weird if your optn is effectively an array od strings. what is the output with `<Text>{example.toString()}</Text>`

Comment: Yeah that's worked . update in your answer i will accept

Answer (score 0):

change `example[0]` to `example`, its not needed. 
when mapping, you get array values, what in your scenario is string, and with `example[0]` you select the first letter of string

```
objAns= this.state.optn.map((example,index) =>{
  return(
    <View  key={index.toString()} >
    <RadioButton currentValue={this.state.value} value={index+1} onPress={this.handleOnPress.bind(this)}>
    <Text>{example}</Text>
    </RadioButton>
  </View>
  );
});
```

Comment: Invariant Violation:Objects are not valid as a react child(found: object with  keys{key,index})

Comment: please show `console.log(example)` and `console.log(this.state.optn)`